# change default payment in ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I have two allowed payment methods, Paypal and Credit card. When a user checks out Pay Pal is selected by default and is shown on top. How do I change the order of these with the credit card option on div on top and make the radio button for credit card, the option selected by default?

Comment: Can you not rearrange the preferred payment methods by going to /admin/store/settings/payment/edit/methods ? (d6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Change the `#weight` attribute so credit card lighter than paypal. Set the `#default` value to credit cards for the radio values.

I haven't used these modules nor have an Ecommerce site live so I cant post example code ...

***EDIT***

install [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and implement `hook_form_alter` for your module. put `dpm($form);dpm($form_id);` in your form atler implementation ... and goto the page with the form in question. You will then see the PHP array structure for the form on the screen.